Why do logical operators not work in conditionals?
I am an absolute beginner, so it is possible that I've missed this--but in my exploration, logical operators like And, Or, Not do not seem to work inside conditionals like If or Which. An example being
If[x OR y, a, b]
Which I interpret to mean "if x or y is the input, then a is the output, otherwise b."
I understand there are workarounds but due to inexperience I cannot understand why this chain of reason shouldn't work. I am trying to write a part of a program currently that depends on a lot of conditionals and keep running into this issue, yet I cannot find a clear answer about this specific question. All related things are much more in depth and I cannot yet fully grasp them. Thank you.

The documentation for Or is a good place to start

You might also look up If, esp. the case If[x || y, a, b, c], which is uncommon, perhaps nonexistent, in procedural programming languages.

If will return a if the first argument evaluates to True. For example, x = True; y = False; If[x || y, a, b] gives a.

Right idea, just not the correct infix form for Or.

I seem to have made And  work. I think the fundamental misunderstanding is the nature of True/False evaluations. That is to say, I believe I am trying to make an If statement that  has two layers; a function with an output, a conditional for the output, and a conditional for the conditional. It seems like there is a point where the output I am evaluating is not True or False so it does not work. Thanks guys!

Your syntax is wrong. Or can be written either by:Or[x,y]or by x||y.
Now, if x and y are not defined the result is unevaluated:
Clear[x,y];    
If[x ||  y, a, b]


If[x ||  y, a, b]

However if x or y is True we get:
x = True;
If[x || y, a, b]

a

And if both are False:
x = y = False;
If[x || y, a, b]

b

